# httpc + many request in spawn not worked

Tags: erlang, request, spawn

I tried to use Erlang's httpc module for high concurrent requests

My code for many requests in spawn hasn't worked:

```
-module(t).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
  ssl:start(),
  inets:start( httpc, [{profile, default}] ),
  httpc:set_options([{max_sessions, 200}, {pipeline_timeout, 20000}], default),

  {ok, Device} = file:open("c:\urls.txt", read),
  read_each_line(Device).

read_each_line(Device) ->
  case io:get_line(Device, "") of
    eof  -> file:close(Device);
    Line -> go( string:substr(Line, 1,length(Line)-1)),
      read_each_line(Device)
  end.

go(Url)->
  spawn(t,geturl, [Url] ).

geturl(Url)->
  UrlHTTP=lists:concat(["http://www.",  Url]),
  io:format(UrlHTTP),io:format("~n"),

  {ok, RequestId}=httpc:request(get,{UrlHTTP,[{"User-Agent", "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10"}]}, [],[{sync, false}]),

  receive
    {http, {RequestId, {_HttpOk, _ResponseHeaders, Body}}} -> io:format("ok"),ok
  end.
```

httpc:request is not received in html Body - if I can use spawn in

```
go(Url)->
      spawn(t,geturl, [Url] ).
```

http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html

**Note**

> If possible the client will keep its connections alive and use
>   persistent connections with or without pipeline depending on
>   configuration and current circumstances. The HTTP/1.1 specification
>   does not provide a guideline for how many requests would be ideal to
>   be sent on a persistent connection, this very much depends on the
>   application. Note that a very long queue of requests may cause a user
>   perceived delay as earlier requests may take a long time to complete.
>   The HTTP/1.1 specification does suggest a limit of 2 persistent
>   connections per server, which is the default value of the max_sessions
>   option

urls.txt contain different urls - for example

```
google.com
amazon.com
alibaba.com
...
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You say it "hasn't worked" but you don't say what that means. What did it do? What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3):

Your code never actually starts the `httpc` service (and `inets`, the application that it depends on), and the confusion probably comes from the unfortunate overloading of the [`inets:start/[0,1,2,3]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html) function:

- [`inets:start/[0,1]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-0) starts the `inets` application itself **and** the `httpc` service with the default profile (called `default`).
- [`inets:start/[2,3]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-1) (which should be called **`start_service`**) starts one of the services that can run atop `inets` (viz. `ftpc`, `tftp`, `httpc`, `httpd`) **once the `inets` application has already started**.

> `start() ->`
> `start(Type) -> ok | {error, Reason}`
>
> Starts the Inets application.

> `start(Service, ServiceConfig) -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Reason}`
> `start(Service, ServiceConfig, How) -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Reason}`
>
> Dynamically starts an Inets service **after
> the Inets application has been started**
>     (with [`inets:start/[0,1]`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-0)).

So your spawned process simply crashed when trying to call `httpc:request/4` as the service itself was not running. To illustrate,  `inets:start( httpc, [{profile, default}] )` from your `start/0` function would fail to start `inets` and the `httpc` service:

```
Eshell V10.7  (abort with ^G)                                                                                                            
1> inets:start(httpc, [{profile, default}]).
{error,inets_not_started}
```

You should check the returned value of application start to track potential problems:

```
...
ok = ssl:start(),
ok = inets:start(),
...
```

Or, if the application could be already started, use a function like this:

```
...
ok = ensure_start(ssl),
ok = ensure_start(inets),
...
ensure_start(M) ->
    case M:start() of
        ok -> ok;
        {error,{already_started,M}} -> ok;
        Other -> Other
    end.
```

**[edit 2 - small code enhancement]**

I have tested this code and it works on my PC. Note that you are using a '' in the string for file access, this is an escape sequence that make the line to fail.

```
-module(t).
-compile(export_all).

start() -> start(2000).

% `To` is a parameter which is passed to `getUrl`
% to change the timeout value. You can  play with 
% it  to  see  the  request queue effect, and how
% much the response times of each site varies.
%
% The default timeout value is set to 2 seconds.
start(To) ->
  ok = ensure_start(ssl),
  ok = ensure_start(inets),
  ok = httpc:set_options([{max_sessions, 200}, {pipeline_timeout, 20000}], default),

  {ok, Device} = file:open("D:/urls.txt", read),
  read_each_line(Device,To).

read_each_line(Device,To) ->
  case io:get_line(Device, "") of
    eof  -> file:close(Device);
    Line -> go( string:substr(Line, 1,length(Line)-1),To),
      read_each_line(Device,To)
  end.

go(Url,To)->
  spawn(t,geturl, [Url,To] ).

geturl(Url,To)->
  UrlHTTP=lists:concat(["http://www.",  Url]),
  io:format(UrlHTTP), io:format("~n"),

  {ok, RequestId}=httpc:request(get,{UrlHTTP,[{"User-Agent", "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10"}]}, [],[{sync, false}]),

  M = receive
        {http, {RequestId, {_HttpOk, _ResponseHeaders, _Body}}} -> ok
      after To ->
        not_ok
      end,
  io:format("httprequest to ~p: ~p~n",[UrlHTTP,M]).

  ensure_start(M) ->
    case M:start() of
        ok -> ok;
        {error,{already_started,M}} -> ok;
        Other -> Other
    end.
```

and in the console:

```
1> t:start().
http://www.povray.org
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
ok
httprequest to "http://www.google.com": ok
httprequest to "http://www.povray.org": ok
httprequest to "http://www.yahoo.com": ok
2> t:start().
http://www.povray.org
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
ok
httprequest to "http://www.google.com": ok
httprequest to "http://www.povray.org": ok
httprequest to "http://www.yahoo.com": ok
3>
```

Note that thanks to the `ensure_start/1` you can launch the application twice.

I have tested also with a bad url and it is detected.

My test include only 3 urls, and I guess that if there are many urls, the time to get the response will increase, because the loop to spawn processes is faster to execute than the request themselves. So you must expect at some point some timeout issue. There may be also some limitation in the http client, I didn't check the doc for this particular point.